# how can the sh python module log stderr/stdout and only capture stdout?

Tags: python, sh

Using the [sh](https://pypi.org/project/sh/) module, I would like to [log](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html) the stdout/stderr of the process and capture stdout for processing. The process may take a long time and logging must not wait until the process is finished so the user sees the output in real time.

The following works fine to log stdout/stderr. But stdout is mixed with stderr and there is no convenient way to separate one from the other.

```py
import sh
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

command = sh.bash('-c', 'echo a; echo b >&2', _iter=True, _err_to_out=True)

for line in command:
    logger.error(line)

print(command.stdout)
```

the output is like this:

```
a
b
b'a\nb\n'
```

Is there a way to do the same but without mixing `stdout` and `stderr`?

Comment: as simple as _err_to_out=False, which anyways is the default value for that variable :)  @singuliere

Comment: if _err_to_out is false, stderr will not be logged

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set [_out](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#out) and [_err](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#err) to the desired logging function ([logging.error](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.error) for instance). It will be called as soon as a new line is read from either `stderr` or `stdout` and the user will be shown the output incrementally.

When `_out` or `_err` are set, however, `sh` does not collect the output and it will not be available for processing. This is what [_tee=True](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#tee) is for: it collects `stdout` and `stderr` even when `_out` or `_err` are set.

```py
import sh
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

command = sh.bash('-c', 'echo a; echo b >&2',
                  _tee=True,
                  _out=lambda x: logger.error(x.strip()),
                  _err=lambda x: logger.error(x.strip()))

print(command.stdout)
```

the output is

```
a
b
b'a\n'
```